# How can I print multiple elements from an array inJavaSCript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was printing elements in Python as I did below but it does not work in JavaScript? Is there any way to print elements like Python in JavaScript?Please, output should be array I don't want to use .join...

array=[1,2,3,4]
print(2:3)

Comment: What is it you expect to happen when you "print" using Javascript?

Comment: `console.log(array.slice(2,3));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use array.slice(2,3) to get part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

We use `console.log()` or `console.count()` (any other functions to check our output in Browser console).

Regarding your question you can try many ways.

```js
const array=[1,2,3,4];

//Method-1
const result1 = array.slice(1,3);
console.log(result1);

// Method-2
const result = array.filter((item,index)=>{
  if(index>=1 && index <=2){
    return item;
  }
});

console.count(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Immutable Solution

The most simplistic immutable way in order to achieve this would be `slice()`.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.
>
> More info: [MDN Webdocs - slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
// immutable
const array = [1,2,3,4];

const sliceArray = array.slice(2,3);
console.log(sliceArray);
```

## Mutable Variant

The mutable variant of this would be a function that splices both sides in a mutable way. JavaScript makes use of 2 `splice()` functions in order to achieve this.

```js
// mutable
const array2 = [1,2,3,4];
((a,b) => {
  array2.splice(b);
    array2.splice(0,a);
})(2,3);
console.log(array2);
```

## Immutable Advanced Solution (filtering on index + value)

Lastly, if you want to make more complex modifications besides checking the index. You can use reduce reconstruct it in an immutable way:

```js
//bonus
const array = [1,2,3,4];

const reduceArray = array.reduce((list, value, index) => (index >= 2 && index < 3 ) ? [...list, value] : list, []);
console.log(reduceArray);
```

Just a reminder if you only need to filter out the values in an immutable way you can use `filter()` for cases like this.

Good luck